# How to detect ODBC DB2 connection encoding (code page)

Tags: c, utf-8, db2, odbc

Is it possible to check which db2 code page is used in communication between ODBC connector and db2 database from c program using ODBC api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indicated by the connection attribute SQL_ATTR_CLIENT_CODEPAGE.

Here's the function to obtain it: [SQLGetConnectAttr](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000600.html)

Comment: Is it part of ODBC standard? Since it is not defined in header files provided with unixodbc.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the manual, for which I included a link? It shows that the function is a part of ODBC 3.0

Comment: Yes, though it seems that it applies only to IMB ODBC implementation, though not 100% sure.